# How to use a variable name for a range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way of using a variable for a range name?

For example I have data for a number of days. I am using `VLOOKUP(5,_day12,3)` to pull some info from the table for day 12. I need to set `_day12` to another already defined range like `_day19`, by replacing `_day12` by a variable, let's call it Range which is in cell A1.  So the formula should be something like `VLOOKUP(5,Range,3)`. I set the content of cell A1 to `_day12` and got `#NA`.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use `INDIRECT`

```
=VLOOKUP("aaa",INDIRECT(C5),1,0)
```

Where `C5` stores the table name.

[image]